# Почему не отображаются "три точки" в Action Bar

Tags: java, android

Захотел в проекте android studio создать контекстное меню, написал следующее в классе MainActivity(Именно для этого активити нужно меню):

```
@Override    
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
}
```

Вот xml код этого меню:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/mnbt1"
            android:title="@string/settings.nazvanie"
            app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
            tools:icon="@drawable/mr_button_light"
            app:showAsAction="never">
        </item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/mnbt2"
            android:title="@string/spravka"
            app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
            tools:icon="@drawable/mr_button_light"
            app:showAsAction="never"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/mnbt3"
            android:title="@string/about"
            app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
            tools:icon="@drawable/mr_button_light"
            app:showAsAction="never"/>
    </menu>
```

И при запуске приложения на мобильное устройство этого самого меню, а точнее "3 точки" нет... Все перепробовал, раньше на старом проекте все работало, а сейчас что-то не то...

Может в API дело? Я использую API 24.
Сам ActionBar есть, но элементы в нем не отображаются... Сам являюсь новичком в сфере разработки мобил. приложений.

Comment: Попробуйте вернуть `return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);` вместо `true`

Comment: Сейчас в Android рекомендуется использовать toolbar вместо actionbar.

Comment: да и это не контекстное меню.  onCreateContextMenu() это разные вещи, лучше начать с Toolbar

Comment: А на каком устройстве смотрите? На некоторых устройствах есть аппаратная кнопка меню, и тогда три точки не будут отображаться. Попробуйте проверить в эмуляторе